# I can not add plugin in pom.xml, i need to make a executable jar of the maven project

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I can not add a plugin in pom.xml file.Help me to fix the issue.
i need this plug in to make a jar file of the project. The plugins tag shows error. I tried these links but can not fix it: http://wiki.netbeans.org/QuickStartJavaMavenProject

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>Restful_java_swing_M</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>



        <name>Restful_java_swing_M</name>


        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
                <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
                <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <properties>
            <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <springframework.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
            <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
            <jackson.library>2.7.5</jackson.library>        
            <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
                <artifactId>AbsoluteLayout</artifactId>
                <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>


        </dependencies>





<p>the plugin tag shows error. </p>


    <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>

                                <mainClass>mainJFrame</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>                        
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>

        </project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of the [Maven Plugins](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html)

> There are the build and the reporting plugins:
>
> ***Build plugins*** will be executed during the build and they should be
>   configured in the `<build/>` element from the POM.
>
> ***Reporting plugins***
>   will be executed during the site generation and they should be
>   configured in the `<reporting/>` element from the POM. Because the
>   result of a Reporting plugin is part of the generated site, Reporting
>   plugins should be both internationalized and localized. You can read
>   more about the localization of our plugins and how you can help.

So for your case, you need to make sure that the plugins are defined under the build element as -

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            ... other details 
        </plugin>
        ... other plugins
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh , I fix the issue. The plugins tag is not showing error bcoz i put a build tag over plugins tag.